# svg use filter from another file

Tags: xml, svg, xlink

I'm trying to define several filters, but don't want them cluttering the main HTML document. I'd like to use relative URIs to reference those filters using relative IRIs, [which the docs indicate should work](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/linking.html#LinksIntoSVG).

**filters.svg**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <filter id="blur" x="-100%" y="-100%" width="300%" height="300%">
            <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

**page.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta chartype="utf-8" />
    <title>Remote Filter Loading</title>
</head>
<body>
    <svg
        id="blurs"
        version="1.1"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    >
        <defs>
            <use xlink:href="filters.svg#blur"></use>
        </defs>

        <circle cx="50" cy="50" fill="red" r="25"
            filter="url(filters.svg#blur)"
        />

        <circle cx="100" cy="50" fill="red" r="25"
            filter="url(#blur)"
        />
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Serving these with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, in Chrome, I expect to see two fuzzy little dots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1E4j.png

(Generated by pasting the filter into the defs directly, which I thought `<use>` did.)

What I get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D2TH.png

**Later**

As @Jason Aller points out, this isn't supported in Chrome. As I mention, my filters don't seem to be working on Firefox. Are there any possible workarounds to keep the  (the actual image has several, and they're rather complex) in a separate file?

Comment: should that #glow be a #blur?

Comment: Yes - the original attempt was a star glow filter, simplified here for a plain blur. The error still exists.

Comment: Hi @DavidSouther, I'm trying to handle this same problem. Did you ever find a good cross-browser solution?

Answer (score 1):

After looking at [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-fragment) and testing I can see it work in Firefox, but not with Chrome.

Comment: Nice call, thanks. Too bad the complex filters I'm running aren't rendering right in Firefox.